# Enable both brotli and gzip on NGINX?

Tags: nginx, gzip

Is it possible to enable both gzip and brotli compression in NGINX?
If the client supports both then return brotli, if only gzip / brotli then return the specicfied, and else if no support for gzip / brotli return plain text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the first articles I found when searching online for nginx and brotli, is [this link](https://medium.com/@blikenoother/nginx-brotli-compression-developed-by-google-which-helps-reducing-18-latency-over-gzip-d9f5f5f28b92). It kind of answers your question — I think:

> Browsers which support brotli send ‘br’ along with ‘gzip’ in accept-encoding request header. If brotli is enabled on your web server, you will get response in brotli compressed format.

This means to me that if the client supports both, brotli is preferred over gzip.

Also note that "Brotli or gzip should not be used for binary files like JPEG, PNG, MP4."

Comment: As I see most servers answers in brotli if there is only brotli in accepted encodings. So works nginx brotli plugin from google for example